# Google Action SmartHome - Publishing a release returns unknown error

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I created a `SmartHome` project with all information provided (all checks are OK in project overview).

When I go to Deploy > Release and click on `Submit Production` then `Submit for review` an error occured:

`Conversation fulfillment ... has invalid API version '0'`

[image: Google SmartHome error]

Any idea whats's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by Google internal team (direct contact to support).

> From aog-support@google.com:
>
> I received a response from our internal team that the issue has been fixed. Please re-submit your Action for review and let us know if the issue still occurs.